# Event Dispatching Problem with Redis Queue

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I've come across a bug in Laravel. I have defined an event to be executed on a queue, and the queue is set up with Redis. This event works perfectly fine in the testing environment without any issues. However, in the production environment, sometimes the event gets dispatched, and sometimes it doesn't. I have checked the worker log, and for the events that don't get dispatched, there is no trace of them.

Dispatch event:

```
 event(new AfterPaymentSuccessEvent($payment->order_id));
```

Listener:

```
class OperationOrder implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $connection = 'redis';
    public $queue = 'medium';
    
    public function handle(AfterPaymentSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        $order = Order::where('id', $event->order)->first();
        $order->update([
            'status' => OrderStatusEnum::Completed
        ]);
    }
}
```

Event:

```
class AfterPaymentSuccessEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public string $order;
    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

The command for run queue:

```
php queue:work  --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600 --queue=high,medium,low
```

EventServiceProvider:

```
 protected $listen = [
        AfterPaymentSuccessEvent::class => [
            OperationOrder::class
        ]
    ];
```

Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code you provided. Possibly it's some conditions in your processing code when event just not firing?

Comment: Thank you for the response, However, no condition is defined for event dispatching.
@lezhni

Comment: Unless you can narrow down the circumstances of when events don't work, your guess is as good as ours. Just make sure (a) your cache is not full (b) you checked your failed jobs table and there's no clue as to what failed. (c) you've checked all possible logs for potential clues (incl. syslog, laravel log, supervisor log if applicable, php-fpm log and even webserver log just in case).